# How to solve this? Error install cryptography for dirsearch tool

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-requests, termux

I don't know why this error, I want to solve this error, so that I can run the dirsearch tool properly.

Note:
pip3 install cryptography not helpful.

[Click to see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ytdE.jpg)

Comment: Please paste the error as text instead of image and add the output of `pip3 install cryptography` too

Comment: As it says in `requirements.txt` of dirsearch,  you need `cryptography>=2.8`, what happens when you install cryptography with pip3? How was that not helpful? It seems to be the obvious solution here.

Comment: Not work. I try pip, pip2, pip3 not work.

Answer (score 0):

use this command

```
python3.7 dirsearch.py
```